# Infinite Canvas background scrolling without hiccups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

The chart below shows how I am making an infinite background scrolling in HTML5/JS. My continuous background is consist of X canvases. I will render the next Canvas immediately before reaching it, and I will release previous Canvas. The problem here is the fact that animation is smooth after rendering, but it has a quick hiccup when it reaches to next frame. because it will render the next frame, logically there will be a quick hiccup.
The problem could be solved using multi-threading in other languages. but this rendering needs DOM so it will be locked.

The question: **How to render next background Canvas in HTML5 without blocking current jQuery animation?**

```
    INIT     > START render 0
 _________
|         |
|    0    |  > render1
|_________|
|         |
|    1    |  > render 2
|_________|
|         |
|    2    |  > render 3
|_________|
|         |
|    ∞    |  > render X
|_________|
```

**Pseudo**

```
var currentSpite = 0;
function goAnimate() {

    render(currentSpite + 1); //50ms hiccup here
    $("#allSpites").animate({ "top": (currentSpite * 1000) + "px" }, 1000, function () {
        goAnimate();
    });
    currentSpite += 1;

    release(currentSpite - 2);
    if (currentSpite > max) return;

}
```

Comment: Please exhibit some code, a 'detail' might be your performance killer. First though is : do you re-use again and again 2 canvases that you swap ? because if you don't, creating a canvas, and garbage collection of disposed canvases can be your performance killer.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Unfortunately no. All canvases are new shapes and there is not any repetitive renders to avoid rendering and just moving spites. It has a huge amount of codes, and rendering performance is good(~30ms). The problem is just hiccups of process for rendering next spite. My question is a logical problem I believe. However, I will provide a pseudo code.

Comment: So first thing is to just swap in between two canvases. You can do it behind the scene without changing much things to your code. Let me know if you want me to explain more.

Comment: @GameAlchemist All canvases should be rendered using new data. Not repetitive. I added Pesudo code to the question above. Thnx!

Comment: You change what data to show, but use the same canvases. The element creation itself may be your bottleneck!

Comment: i understand, but you can handle, behind the scene, just two canvases, that you clearRect in between use. The swap is to be done in render() or release(), and implies adjusting some css properties. I insist because creating a canvas + g.c. has a huge cost.

Comment: @GameAlchemist I create 50+ div elements on page initialization. Then I will  render them one-by-one using KineticJs and above algorithm. Do you believe re-rendering available canvases has a significant impact?

Comment: got to go now, but last words : 1) 30 ms is not a good rendering performance. With one single canvas on which you re-paint everything on each frame (with requestAnimationFrame), you'll get 60 fps (16ms) see here if in doubt : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/5VJhp/. You can still use Kinetics and translate the canvas before a call. 2) Creating a canvas can last from 4 to 12 ms 3) garbage collector can last from 2 to 10ms 4) show some pseudo code for render and release. 5) Good luck :-)

Comment: @GameAlchemist Thank you, After test I will notify you

Comment: @GameAlchemist I changed KineticJS to native HTML5 Canvas, And render time decreased to 9ms. It is great now. Improving rendering function was the solution. Please submit your solution in comment, so I can mark it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comments, creating a canvas is not something you want to do within an animation loop : it takes several milliseconds to do so, which is enough to switch from 60fps to 30 (or 50 to 25), since you already have some drawings to do.
Worst thing is that if you create canvas then 'dispose' of them, they'll have to be garbage collected, which is another 'long' pause for your app.

My first though was to use two canvases and to swap them through css. But i just did a quick test and smoothness was poor  : to many reflow i guess.
Smoothness had little to see with a small scrolling demo i did some time ago using only a single canvas ( jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/5VJhp ) .

So final advice was to use only one single canvas, clear it on each frame, and draw the two required 'render' with KinectJS, just translating the canvas before the draw to adjust coordinates.

It seems to work, since with 9ms you even have a few ms left within the 16ms of 60fps : sweet ! :-)